# R visualize cca plot in ggplot,

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I've a problem with visualising a cca plot in ggplot.
I've a dataset with 4 species(PF,IF,MM,IM) and 3 environmental variables taken during 8 months along 4 stations, 
I want to see for which species and which months/stations? which environmental variable(s) is/are important and
I want to visualize this in a nice cca plot in ggplot. I've been searching for some R code but it seems quite new to visualize
this..

This is my data:

[image]

I would like to have a graph like this:

[image]

Comment: Please don't put your images onto a SPAM/pop-up showing website. And certainly don't use images to send us snippets of data - just copy/paste the text into the Q.

Answer (score 7):

This is relatively easy (*^*) with the **ggvegan** package.

First you need to install **devtools** and then use that to install the **ggvegan** package from github:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("gavinsimpson/ggvegan")
```

Next, do a CCA, here I'm using the example from `?cca`

```
library("vegan")
library("ggvegan")
data(varespec, varechem)
vare.cca <- cca(varespec, varechem)
```

Then, to generate a ggplot version of the CCA triplot, use:

```
autoplot(vare.cca)
```

This gives:

[image]

If you just want the data back in a ggplot-required form, use the `fortify()` method:

```
fdat <- fortify(vare.cca)
head(fdat)

> head(fdat)
         Dim1        Dim2   Score    Label
1  0.07534683 -0.93580864 species Callvulg
2 -0.18133963  0.07610159 species Empenigr
3 -1.05354930 -0.06026078 species Rhodtome
4 -1.27742838  0.30758571 species Vaccmyrt
5 -0.15256316  0.12053851 species Vaccviti
6  0.24295573  0.26432438 species Pinusylv
```

The object returned by `autoplot()` is a ggplot object so you can add to the plot using that system:

```
plt <- autoplot(vare.cca)
class(plt)
str(plt, max = 2)

> class(plt)
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
> str(plt, max = 2)
List of 9
 $ data       : list()
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "waiver"
 $ layers     :List of 3
  ..$ :Classes 'proto', 'environment' <environment: 0xa1847d8> 
  ..$ :Classes 'proto', 'environment' <environment: 0x98ef158> 
  ..$ :Classes 'proto', 'environment' <environment: 0xa0d1cf8> 
 $ scales     :Reference class 'Scales' [package "ggplot2"] with 1 fields
  ..and 21 methods, of which 9 are possibly relevant:
  ..  add, clone, find, get_scales, has_scale, initialize, input, n,
  ..  non_position_scales
 $ mapping    : list()
 $ theme      : list()
 $ coordinates:List of 2
  ..$ limits:List of 2
  ..$ ratio : num 1
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "fixed" "cartesian" "coord"
 $ facet      :List of 1
  ..$ shrink: logi TRUE
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "null" "facet"
 $ plot_env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
 $ labels     :List of 7
  ..$ y     : chr "CCA2"
  ..$ x     : chr "CCA1"
  ..$ shape : chr "Score"
  ..$ colour: chr "Score"
  ..$ xend  : chr "Dim1"
  ..$ yend  : chr "Dim2"
  ..$ label : chr "Label"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
```

*^: Depending on how much customisation you want...*

Comment: Also, I've assumed you can or want to use **vegan** to do the CCA. Otherwise, you are on your own; you need to massage the data into a format similar to what I show in the line `head(fdat)` by extracting information from whatever software you are using to fit the CCA.

Comment: ok, thanks, I already used autoplot, but i want to customize the plot further, add species labels, add clusters(months), change panel background color..

Comment: or do you mean If I use fortify i can use it like a normal ggplot and customize it? but how do I turn on the labels then?

Comment: You can do `autoplot(vare.cca, geom = "text")` to get species and site labels instead of points. I have no idea what "clusters(months)` means. If you want to change the background you would change it as with any other ggplot plot. A simple expedient might be to use `autoplot(vare.cca, geom = "text") + theme_bw()`. If that is not sufficient, you need to look at the documentation for **ggplot2** to see how to achieve what you want to with that package.

Comment: I meant to have text for the species, and colors for the sites, like green for the four stations of february,.. so it isn't too crowded on the plot. Thanks a lot

Comment: I think there is a bug in the `autoplot.cca()` method which is not allowing the control I envisaged for this; you should be able to do `autoplot(vare.cca, geom = c("text","point"))` for example to have species labels and samples as points. If you want further customisation, you need to use the `fortify()` method to extract the ordination data in the format suitable for ggplot, augment this with the information about the month to which each sample belongs, then do your own ggplot plot using `ggplot()`.

Comment: ok and then  after I use the fortify method I should use coord_cartesian() to plot the coordinates?

Comment: Nope, `coord_fixed()` is required as the axes need to scaled in the same units. See `ggvegan:::autoplot.cca` for details of how I constructed the ggplot object if you want more details, or see the [code on github](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan/blob/master/R/autoplot.cca.R)